# How to make square CardView (Android)

Tags: android, android-cardview

How to make square `CardView`.

When I set the `layout_weight`  on `CardView` it is not set like square on `CardView`.

Please give me a solution : (without set the fixed height and width)

See picture below:
[image]

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/silver"
                        tools:ignore="NestedWeights">


                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/silver">


                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="4dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/silver">


                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Like square? In terms of geometry? Just set the same value for width and height and you can give it some elevation too.. Post your XML if you're still stuck.

Comment: You could use fixed height and width on your CardView. It seems like you only have two sizes, the big one on the left and small ones on the right. Layout weight is not the best way to go if you want to support different screen sizes.

Comment: Nested weights are bad for performance, use a `ConstraintLayout` instead

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a `ConstraintLayout` instead of multiple `LinearLayout` with weight.

Add

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

in your `build.gradle`. Then you can try something like that (with dimensionRatio set to 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="4dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/no_picture" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/card3"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/card1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/no_picture" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/card1"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/card2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/card2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/no_picture" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Having known the advantages of ConstraintLayout, it's the only layout I ever use! Must know features of ConstraintLayout include Barriers, Groups, Chains etc...

Answer (score 4):

you could use a custom CardView, and override onMeasure() to force a 1:1 aspect ratio

```
public class SquareCardView extends CardView {

    public SquareCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int ignoredHeightMeasureSpec) {
        int newHeightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec;
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Then use this code in your xml

```
<com.example.view.SquareCardView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1">
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/square1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_dark"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</com.example.view.SquareCardView>
```

Comment: but it's not set with 1:1 aspect ration